# C on Windows: Bind to a free random port and get the port number

Tags: c, sockets

On linux i would do:

```
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(0);

if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
{
    perror("ERROR on binding");
    *err = -2;
}
struct sockaddr_in sin;
socklen_t len = sizeof(sin);

if (getsockname(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, &len) == -1)
{
    *err = -2;
    perror("getsockname");
}
```

In Windows i have:

```
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
//using 0 instead of DEFAULT_PORT gives me host not found.
iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result); 
ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);

socklen_t len = sizeof(result->ai_addr);
printf("Port number: %d", getsockname(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, &len));

iResult = bind( ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);

freeaddrinfo(result);
iResult = listen(ListenSocket, 4);
```

Thanks

Comment: First, you're using `result->ai_addr` after you call `freeaddrinfo( result );`.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewHenle! Fixed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows works the same as Linux here.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737550(v=vs.85).aspx

Doesn't your Linux code just work on windows? Really it should be possible to write code which works on both, apart from a couple of corner cases and initializing winsock (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742213(v=vs.85).aspx).